# How to create line + ribbon plot with seaborn.objects?

Tags: python, seaborn, seaborn-0.12.x

I would like to create a line + ribbon plot similar to [these ones created with ggplot2 using `geom_line + geom_ribbon`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_ribbon.html):

[image: line and ribbon plot]

For that, I would like to use [the new `seaborn.objects` interface](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/objects_interface.html), but even though the `Plot` function does accept `ymin` and `ymax`, I don't know how to use them effectively. I'm trying out several combinations of `.add(so.Line()).add(so.Area())` but getting various errors or not the result I want.

Sample data:

```
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

pl.DataFrame({"value": np.random.randn(10), "std": 0.2 * np.abs(np.random.randn(10))})
```

Example output using matplotlib `Axes.fill_between`:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`seaborn.objects.Band`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.objects.Band.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn.objects as so

df = pd.DataFrame({"value": np.random.randn(10), "std": 0.2 * np.abs(np.random.randn(10))})

(
    so.Plot(
        x=df.index,
        y=df["value"],
        ymin=df.eval("value - std"),
        ymax=df.eval("value + std")
    )
    .add(so.Line())
    .add(so.Band())
)
```

[image]